# why develop in windows/desktop application?

Tags: desktop-application

Just wondering what your comments are regarding the current trend as everything is moving to the web or even the cloud. The significance of an OS or desktop application is getting less attention than web application. So to those folks out there who still develop windows applications, such as WPF. Why still do it? Why not move to web programming? Silverlight instead for example...

Comment: This should probably be marked as a community wiki.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because there are still levels of **security** and **interactivity** that you can deliver with a Desktop Application rather than a Web Application.

Answer (score 9):

One reason is performance. Web applications will always run in a sandbox and won't have full access to native resources. Thus, they can't be as fast as a desktop applications. This is very important for applications like IDEs, CAD systems and games.

Answer (score 8):

The applications I've running right now:

- excel
- wireshark
- winzip
- file manager
- several ssh consolees

I don't see what benefit any of those(perhaps bar Excel - but if you ever tried to make a big pivot table with html + ajax, you're just annoying your users) would have as a web application. People make a lot of applications with similar needs. It'd also be silly to enforce a network/web connection for applications that doesn't strictly need it.

Silverlight is something inbetween, I'm not sure I'd consider it a typical "web" application, more a web deployed application with some sandboxing - though the distinctions get blurry.

Answer (score 6):

A well designed desktop app will usually be considerably more usable than a well designed web app. This is because a web app is limited by what is allowed by the browser, limited by the fact that the browser has controls (toolbar buttons, menus, etc) that aren't related to the application, limited by latency inherent in the network, etc.

For many types of problems this isn't important, and the benefits of a web based app outweigh the usability concerns. But at least with the state of the browser today, very few web apps can complete with a desktop app in the areas of usability and responsiveness.

By "web app", I mean one whose UI is based on a browser, and which interacts with a data model that is largely across the network. By "desktop app" I mean one using native controls, interacting with a local data model, or one on a LAN.

Answer (score 2):

By now

- Desktop software is faster (you haven't to go for a network to read/write/process data)
- Hardware Access is easier and preferable to execute locally because security
- Don't needing an internet connection can be good ( for example a laptop needing to connect internet for listening a mp3 or viewing your own photos won't be faster neither private enough)

Perhap one day it will be preferable and faster a cloud than a local storage, but whenever we were looking for a stand alone, fail safe, or minimalist, we will need to be unplugged

Comment: We (developers) should remember that some system "can exist" unplugged, because it's good that a refrigerator has internet access, but perhaps it's not necessary

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a direct disconnect between desktop applications and web development/the cloud. Whether the UI layer is a website or an application, the cloud can still back your application. I think thin clients are on the rise, of which RIA technologies like silverlight are just one facilitator.

That said, some tasks just make more sense to do locally. If I had to connect to the cloud to build my console java applications, I would be rather upset.

Answer (score 1):

I am sick and tired of the continuous division of "web app vs. desktop app".

**There's no such thing as a "web app"** - the HTML and the JavaScript are executed on your desktop by the browser; they just happen to be delivered on demand when you navigate to the URL. But even that might not be true, if they happen to be in the cache.

What people usually consider a "web app" is a browser-hosted app that happens to be manipulating resources hosted on the cloud; and quite often this manipulation happens to involve code running on the server as well.

But there's nothing that prevents a "desktop app" to be just a rich front-end for the user manipulating a cloud-based resources. Just look at all the WPF, Air and Objective-C Twitter clients out there.

Also, there's nothing that prevents you from delivering an browser-hosted HTML5/JS based app that manipulates local resources only. Just look at the3 canonical example of a "web app" - Gmail and it's ability to work offline, without network access.

Not to mention that with all the advances in the browsers and the RIA platforms (both Flash and Silverlight) - removing the browser chrome, separating tabs in processes, suporting out-of-browser execution, what is considered a "web app" nowadays is quickly transitioning to something that you should be better called a "light-weight desktop app" or "portable desktop app". :-)

**The real division is "rich apps" vs. "reach apps".** Developers might be investing heavily into implementing a rich application that relies heavily on the abilities of a particular platform to deliver a level of user experience that can't be implemented otherwise. Or they might want to invest heavily into implementing an application that aim to reach to as many user as possible, on as many platforms as possible and are willing to limit the user experience in certain ways in favor of penetration.

**In that context, you question becomes moot.** The choice of a presentation layer is completely orthogonal from the choice of the location of the resources your application manipulates.

Comment: For the downvoters - I really want to hear what exactly you disagree with in my answer. And I want to hear a definition of a "web app" and a "desktop app" and where is the exact border between them.

Comment: I downvoted because your answer sounds more like a rant rather than constructively addressing the question. The notion of "web app" and "desktop app" is fairly well known to most technologists. To claim there is no distinction may make for an interesting blog post but it doesn't answer the question that was asked.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley - yes, it is a rant. But it's also an answer - there is no distinction between web and desktop nowadays. Especially with the latest developments in Windows 8, where the predominant technology for building desktop applications for the immersive shell is [gasp!] HTML5 and JS.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley - yes, it is a rant. But it's also an answer - there is no distinction between web and desktop nowadays. Especially with the latest developments in Windows 8, where the predominant technology for building desktop applications for the immersive shell is [gasp!] HTML5 and JS.

"The notion of "web app" and "desktop app" is fairly well known to most technologists" - can you elaborate on that notion? Can you actually come up with a reliable criteria by which you can judge whether an application is a "web" vs. "desktop"?

Comment: Sure, I can come up with the criteria. If the UI is based on a browser it's a web app. If you have to get a UI component served up by a remote machine, it's a web app. If you're using a traditional GUI toolkit (winforms, X11, Cocoa, etc) it's a desktop app. Sure, there's grey area in-between those, but that's the general idea.

Comment: "If the UI is based on a browser it's a web app" - So, the Windows 8 HTML5 apps are web apps for you? They are not using "traditional" GUI toolkit, and their UI is being rendered by Trident (the IE rendering engine)

"If you have to get a UI component served up by a remote machine, it's a web app." - I've seen quite a few apps not based on browser, and using "traditional" GUI toolkit (namely WPF), where UI components are served by a remote machine (both XAML and code behind).

Comment: If the "windows 8 HTML5 apps" run in a browser and connect to a remote server then yes, they are a web app.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the environment.  A corporate user can be expected to be online all/most of the time, whereas someone at home may not be connected continually.  Plus you then have the various security issues, control, and update problems that you run into with every app.  In a business environment, web apps are great because you can update the application once and everyone immediately sees the change.  I do this type of work now.  But most of the apps are data driven web apps.  For something graphical or processor intensive, you'd want to work at the desktop level (like a few other people above mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

The reason so many applications are going web based is simple, it's more profitable. If I license you an application to run locally you pay the price if there's value only once and as has been stated before you aren't dependent on access to the web. If I make it a web service NOW you pay for a MONTHLY subscription plus any additional fees for going over your anticipated agreed upon services,... FOREVER. You're also at the mercy of any changes made, I collect and sell data on everything you do with it, and you are my cash cow which I'll milk until you get upset, then offer you a special deal to keep you interested.

Local applications are superior in mission critical circumstances where you or the company you work for cannot afford to retrain every 6 months to a year, need fewer barriers to entry in the case of expansion, and have the ability to interact openly with the API to integrate sweeping changes (Hence the API on the OS which is far more difficult to interact with in web applications due to security and support issues.)

Overall, if the software application you intend to develop is meant to make you a lot of money and cause certain difficulties and security concerns on the user end, web applications are perfect for you.

If you are interested in creating a stable application of limited scope to resolve a specific issue in a defined industry, a native application is the best.

The best of both worlds is to write your base code using a consul, ensure the inner working are correctly operating and returning the most efficient results, then develop UI/UX both natively and web service packages given the customer versatility in their options. A core first approach allows controlled functionality development. Once complete switch to user centered and defined UI/UX development.